# Clear sqlite db when application closes android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to delete my sqlite database when the application closes. I tried using a global class and overidded the onTerminate() method.

```
public class AppController extends Application {

private static AppController mInstance;

public Context context(){
    return mInstance.getApplicationContext();

}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    context().deleteDatabase(DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
    super.onTerminate();
}

}
```

Its not working

Comment: if you need to delete it every time the application closes, why using a db when the main porpouse of it is saving data when application is closed? it's like demolishing a house every time you go out

Comment: what is "context()" here ? , what is happening in deleteDatabase method? Have you set this application class in your application manifest?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley what do you suggest

Comment: Honestly depends on how many entities and which operations you need to know. If one entity per type you can also use static classes. for only low numbers of data (like strings or some fields) you can use sharedpreferences, ...

Answer (score 5):

For an in-memory database that is not persisted to permanent storage, use `null` as the database file name.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I like the alternative solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: @leoderprofi this solve it. the method he provided deletes automatically the database every time you close the application. (as he said, not persistent to permanent storage)

Comment: Technically yes, but there are cases when it doesn't solve the exact question, e.g. when he wants to open a database from persistant storage that was created by an other process and delete that after the application executed.

Comment: How do I use null as the database file name

Comment: @Hidee I guess it's `DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME` that you're passing to `SQLiteOpenHelper` super constructor.

Comment: @laalto yes, its DbHelper.DATABASE_NAME that I'm passing to the super constructor. so should i use context().deleteDatabase(null) ?

Comment: @Hidee no - just forget about deleting databases altogether. Instead change `DATABASE_NAME` to null.

Comment: It still doesnt work.. am i supposed to implement it in the onTerminate() method. Or is there any other method. thanks

Comment: @Hidee You give the `null` as database name when opening it.